# VS 2017 Debugger variable preview is wrong

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a strange behavior when debugging in Visual Studio 2017 with the preview of variables, if a variable-name is used more than ones, in different scopes.

Here is a simple sample:

```
private void Test()
{
    var values = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    if (values.Count > 20)
    {
        var a = 0;
        a = values[5];
    }
    else
    {
        var a = 0;
        a = values[5];
    }
}
```

The bebugger preview told me, that "a" in the second scope is zero.

[image: behavior that is not expected]

If i change the variable in the bottom scope to "b" everything works fine...

[image: everything is fine]

Is that the normal behavior of the debugger? Cant remember...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Fody caused this behavior. After deinstalling Fody, the debugger works as expected!

Fody (Version 1.29.4) / PropertyChanged.Fody (Version 1.52.1)